# How to configure application.config.php

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I am using Zf2,somehow cloned zf3, the application.config.php is still zf2which has my modules configured, but it threw exception for not able to find Route from ServiceManager.

How to add the modules config to my app?
The two application config are different.

Thanks,
W.

Comment: can you share your "application.config.php" and also exceptions

Answer (score 0):

`application.config.php` should describe all the Modules the system needs.
For example:

```
return [
    'modules' => [
    'Application',
    'Module1',
    'Module2',
    ],
    'module_listener_options' => [
    'config_glob_paths' => [
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php'
    ],
    'config_cache_enabled' => false,
    'cache_dir' => 'data/cache',
    'module_paths' => [
        './module',
        './vendor'
    ]
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
    'use_defaults' => true,
    'factories' => []
    ]
];
```

Than `ZF` will read each module `Module.php` file and load the associated config files  using the method `getConfig()`

The default is:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```

For example, you can:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    $user = include __DIR__ . '/config/user.config.php';
    $group = include __DIR__ . '/config/group.config.php';
    $account = include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    return array_merge_recursive($user, $group, $account);
}
```

Comment: The app config doesn’t use the format, how after find it:https://github.com/nginadofficial/nginad/blob/master/upload/config/application.config.php @michaelbn

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you download the [SkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication), which is setup for learning purposes. It clearly illustrates and explains the different defaults in the config. Default [`application.config.php` here](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/config/application.config.php)

In this default config you'll find this:

```
// Retrieve list of modules used in this application.
'modules' => require __DIR__ . '/modules.config.php',
```

As such, you have a separate `modules.config.php` next to the `application.config.php` to separate these concerns. By default it looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2016 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */
/**
 * List of enabled modules for this application.
 *
 * This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
 */
return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application',
];
```

Though after you run `composer install` more will like be added here.

In the Skeleton's only module (`Application`), you'll also find a [`Module.php`](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/src/Module.php) in the `src/` folder. This is where module config gets loaded from/by.

This is where I would recommend you start to deviate a bit from the default setup, by creating your own AbstractModule class in a generic module (MVC?) somewhere. I recommend this to minimize the amount of duplicated code, as most modules will not have more than a simple "here's the config, do your thing", like the default linked above.

My own `Module.php` classes look like this:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(__DIR__, __NAMESPACE__);
    }
}
```

And the `AbstractModule` is this:

```
abstract class AbstractModule implements ConfigProviderInterface, AutoloaderProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var String Path of current module
     */
    protected $path;

    /**
     * @var String Namespace of current module
     */
    protected $namespace;

    /**
     * This is to be called by descendant classes with:
     * parent::__construct(__DIR__, __NAMESPACE__)
     *
     * @param $path      string Module path
     * @param $namespace string Module namespace
     */
    public function __construct($path, $namespace)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->namespace = $namespace;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = [];

        $path = $this->path 
            . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' 
            . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config' 
            . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.php';

        foreach (glob($path) as $filename) {
            $config = array_merge_recursive($config, include $filename);
        }

        return $config;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return [
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => [
                'namespaces' => [
                    $this->namespace => $this->path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'src',
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

This setup would still allow you to modify the `Module.php` of a specific module and it's generic in such a way that you require only that `__construct` function the child-classes if you need do nothing else.

Note, this setup takes any `.php` files in the `config/` folder. So you could develop your own packages to include with default config `.dist` files and still use this class.